# Free media player that has gradient highlighting effects?

Tags: gratis, media-player

I need a media player that show this type of effect:

[image]

Is there a free media player that has gradient highlighting effects?

Answer (score 1):

A web browser?

You simply prepare a webpage with:

> iframe {
>     margin: auto;
>     display: block;
>     box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px #FFF;
>     position: absolute;
>     top: 50%;
>     left: 50%;
>     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}

https://jsfiddle.net/wz4s3ku3/

And insert your youtube iframe link inside.